# Why would a merged file be one less line than its input files?

Tags: python, file, merging-data

I'm doing some multithread webscraping and write 100 lines per thread into 100 files. I check to make sure every file has 100 lines then I merge. Then I check to make sure the merged file has 10000 lines. Only this time, the merged file seems to be one line short. All other runs have had 10000 lines. Any idea why a merged file would have one line less? Here's the code I'm using to merge. I've checked that all input files have 100 lines. They all do. So I'm not sure why the merged file has one line less.

```
with open(rf"data\run12.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as infile:
            for line in infile: 
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: One of the files doesn't have a newline at the end of its last line. So its last line is being combined with the first line of the next file.

Comment: Are different threads writing to the same file?

Comment: Why are you reading the files line by line? You can just do `outfile.write(infile.read())` to do it all in one shot. But this won't solve the above problem.

Comment: Can you merge the files via some other reliable method (perhaps with `cat *.txt > mergedfile`), and then compare that file with the merged file produced by your program?  Seeing the line that is different might prove useful.

Comment: is it possible the way you are counting lines is different from the way you are reading lines? for example, maybe your line counter is finding one more end of line character than your line reader, might be interesting to readlines() and check the number of lines, then look more closely at any file with < 100 in the line list.

Comment: I appreciate the rapid response wow was not expecting that (first question on here). One of the threads failed on the last line of the file, so it didn't write a newline, and the method that restarts failed threads didn't notice because the file was still 100 lines long. I used len(f.readlines()) as my check. Thanks for teaching me the other merge methods!

Comment: I'll have to look into why I've heard that `outfile.write(infile.read())` shouldn't be used for large files, but I guess a 100 line file is still pretty small anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when the very last line of the file isn't a new line. One of my input files didn't write a newline at the end, so I had 100 lines in every input file, but only 9999 lines in the output due to that lack of a newline character at the end of one input file causing its last line to merge with the first line of the adjacent input file.